# How can I link to a cell in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a headings and every time I have to scroll down to the cell I need.

Can I create some kind of "header" on the top of the page and just click on the header I want and it will automatically scroll down?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script:

```
function onOpen() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var entries = [{name:"MyFunction", functionName:"myFunction"}];
    sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries);
};

function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var mysheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    var input = Browser.inputBox("Input", "Input Row No. To Navigate:", Browser.Buttons.OK);
    mysheet.setActiveCell(mysheet.getDataRange().offset(input-1, 0, 1, 1));
};
```

As soon as you input the row number, you will be navigated to the "Cell" which is at the first Column in that row.

And in `onOpen()` function, I have coded to insert `myFunction` in the "Scripts" menu at the menu bar. I have entered this function in the script so that you don't have to run the script from script editor again and again and so that you can do it directly from the menu bar.

Comment: Please stop linking to your own blog. You should copy the solution into the answer instead of just a link.

Answer (score 0):

In this video you will find the solution! Have a look to that channel, always work with me!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBhewDy4fFY

Comment: Please explain the answer here. Just linking to a video isn't actually answering the question.